# port forwarding not working with python sockets

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, portforwarding

I am learning how to use python sockets right now, and now I am trying to use the simple chat program that I created to talk with one of my friends. of course, the porgram didnt work because I didnt port forward it.

I have forwarded port 21342 using the ip (the ip is static) I found at `whatismyip.com` as my external ip and the ip shown as the ipv4 in the oputput of the `ipconfig` command in the `cmd` as the internal ip.

now, even after forwarding it still isnt working. am I still missing something obvious or is this a real issue?

code:

server:

```
import socket
import threading as thread

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
sock.bind((host , 21342))
sock.listen(5)
connections = []
def chat(client , address):
    global connections
    while True:
        info = client.recv(1024)
        for connection in connections:
            if connection != client:
                connection.send(info)
        if not info:
            connections.remove(client)
            client.close()
            break
try:
    while True:
        client , address = sock.accept()
        print 'new connection!'
        client_thread = thread.Thread(target = chat , args = (client , address))
        client_thread.daemon = True
        client_thread.start()
        connections.append(client)
    sock.close()
except:
    for connection in connections:
        connection.close()
    sock.close()
```

client:

```
import socket
import threading as thread

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'ip found at whatsmyip.com'
sock.connect((host , 21342))
def get_info(sock):
    while True:
        print sock.recv(1024)
get_info_thread = thread.Thread(target = get_info , args = [sock])
get_info_thread.daemon = True
get_info_thread.start()
while True:
    sock.send(raw_input())
sock.close()
```

Comment: Did you disable the firewall (if any)?
What if running server.py and client.py on the same machine?

Comment: @user1034937 yes. should I add that to the post?

Comment: @user1034937 if on the same machine it works like a charm

Comment: "does not work" is no useful error description. What is the expected behavior? What happens instead? Please include any error messages you get in detail in your question (not as comment).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thats the thing. the only error message I get is the usual unable to connect message that happens when you input the wrong socket number or open the client without opening the server

Comment: @javajav: Can you connect from a different machine in the local network to the lP of the machine in the local network? If not then the firewall in Windows or maybe a firewall on the router is blocking access. If you can connect from the local network but not from a remote network port forwarding is not properly setup. If you instead try to connect to the public IP from inside the same local network and it fails then your router does not support [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried just now and I can connect from other computers on the same network.

Comment: @javajav: This addresses only the first of the three points I made to help you figure out where the problem is. What about the other two?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I dont understand the second point, but as you can see in the code snippet I do use the public address and it does work localy